# Interpreting results of resemblance-based permutation methods: PERMANOVA and PERMDISP?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, unbalanced-classes, biostatistics, post-hoc, permutation-test

I am working with an invertebrate data set (i.e., counts of individuals per invertebrate order, captured by pitfall trap) and am exploring trends in community composition in relation to environmental attributes. In particular, I am exploring if there are differences in community composition (as captured through pitfall traps) between two neighboring islands by visually exploring trends via NMDS (with wisconsin standardization, using Bray-curtis dissimilarity) as well as post-hoc/resemblance-based permutation methods. My experimental design, though, is unbalanced, as I have 329 samples from island 1 and 121 samples from island 2.

First, I used a PERMANOVA to detect differences in the locations (centroids) of my two groups (island 1 and island 2). When using the PERMANOVA test, it specifically tests the null hypothesis: "the centroids of the groups, as defined in the space of the chosen resemblance measure are equal for all groups." So, as explained in Anderson and Walsh (2013), if one were to fail to reject the null hypothesis, then any observed differences between the centroids in the data set would be similar in size to what would be obtained under random allocation of individual sample units to the groups. When I used the PERMANOVA test on my data set, I had the following result (F = 37.826, R2 = 0.07786, and p < 0.001). 
However, Anderson (2001, Fig. 4) warns that the method may confound location and dispersion effects: significant differences may be caused by different within-group variation (dispersion) instead of different mean values of the groups. PERMDISP is a common test completed in conjunction with PERMANOVA and tests the null hypothesis of "no difference in dispersion between groups." This test can be quite helpful, as it can identify if it is the dispersion of the group data from the centroids that is driving the significance (of the PERMANOVA test) or if it is the centroids of the group data themselves. However, for both the PERMANOVA and PERMDISP tests, it is ideal to have equal sample sizes to include this; unbalanced experimental designs can either increase rejection rates or the test can become more conservative.

In any case, I ran the PERMDISP test on my data and received this result: F = 48.346 and p < 0.001. Given that I have unequal sample sizes between my groups, I cannot conclude if it is dispersion alone or both dispersion and centroid differences that are driving/affecting the result of the PERMANOVA test.
So, my question is--with an unequal experimental design (something that I can't change), what the best steps for trying to interpret trends in this kind of ecological data, given the significant test results from both PERMANOVA and PERMDISP? What are the next logical steps from here?

Comment: If it is not too late to help, Anderson suggest an extension of the usual PERMANOVA to account for unbalanced designs and dispersion. A quick account of it is given in section 4 of https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/9781118445112.stat07841 Hope this can help.

Comment: May I know how do you solved this problem?